# How to get the object key and value from another javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, glob, acorn

i am using $ npm run index.js

in index.js file i am looping and get list of below files, from the file we need to read the "testData", could you please help to get the data

```
var listOfFiles = ['test/fileOne.js',
,test/example.js,]
```

each file having

```
/test/fileOne.js

var testData = {
    tags: 'tag1 tag2 tag3',
    setup: 'one_tier'
}
```

```
/test/example.js

var testData = {
    tags: 'tag3',
    setup: 'two_tier'
}
```

My Code: index.js

```
let fs = require("fs")
const glob = require("glob");

var getDirectories = function (src, callback) {
    glob(src + '/**/*.js', callback);
};
getDirectories('tests', function (err, res) {
if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
} 
else {
    var listOfFiles = res;
    for (let val of listOfFiles){
       ///// HERE we have to get the Tags and setup from each js file////
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add export {testData} at the end of each file_x.js, and import them with `import test1 from test_1.js` and use them as `test1.testData`

Comment: If you can't modify the `test_xx.js` files to export the data, then you'll have to read the files into mmeory and `eval()` them and then reference the `testData` variable they produce in your scope.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius we can not import the specific file, its dynamic files inside test folder 

for (let val of listOfFiles){
       ///// HERE we have to get the Tags and setup from each js file////
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can read the content of the file as string using `fs.readFileSync`:

```
for (const val of listOfFiles) {
    ///// HERE we have to get the Tags and setup from each js file////
    const content = fs.readFileSync(val, 'utf8');
    console.log(content);
    const tags = content.match(/tags: '(.*?)'/)[1];
    console.log(tags);
    const setup = content.match(/setup: '(.*?)'/)[1];
    console.log(setup);
}
```